# Protect CGI-BIN directory access

Tags: php, .htaccess, raspberry-pi, apache2, cgi-bin

I am running apache2 on a raspberry pi.  I have a simple php login portal using a mysql database for authentication.
Once logged in, the user is presented with a page containing buttons to interact with the gpio pins via a javascript call to a bash script in the cgi-bin directory.
That part is working fine.
What I realized is that a random person could type in
    for example: http:///cgi-bin/pulse.cgi
and initiate the script without being logged in. 
I am looking for guidance to protect the cgi-bin directory and verify a logged in user is accessing the bash script. I have tried using htaccess with basic user/passwords, but that defeats the purpose of having the php login unless I can pass the session to htaccess?